# EJS - pass data to partial view and use it in every view/page. How can i do that?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using ejs as a template engine for my NodeApp and I have to use a partial view containing dynamic data in every page/view. I don't want to pass data from every router to render it. is it possible that I pass the data once and use it anywhere independent of the router? For example, in a navigation bar, I am displaying user info with some notifications and I have to use this navbar all over my site. How can I achieve it without repassing the data?

Note: this question is a repost of https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3858, I'm posting it here because I didn't found any solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you trying to do is to display content from two different COLLECTION on a single page, what you would have to is something like this on the backend, lets say its lists of PRODUCTS you want to fetch in your partial :

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
const page = req.query.page;
let user;
let hasUser;
User.find().sort('-_id').then(users => {

        user = users
        hasUser = users.length > 0
        return Product.find().sort('-_id')
    })
    .then(products => {
        res.render('index', {
            prods: products,
            title: 'Ecommerce Site',
            path: '/',
            admin: false,
            hasProduct: products.length > 0,
            activeHome: true,
            isLoggedIn: req.session.isLoggedIn,
            user: user,
            hasUser: hasUser,
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

}

The next step is to go into your partial file and write your syntax for it to fetch the data, but on every page/view you would want to apply the partials, you would have to do a `return Product.find()`